# Migrating from Cordova to Capacitor

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]
Hello i 've decided to migrate from Cordova to Capacitor  on my Ionic/Angular project. I have created a new capacitor project following the instructions https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/getting-started/with-ionic

Now i have installed some plugins as you may see on the screenshot i attached.

I copy paste the app folder from my cordova project to my new capacitor app folder.

Obviously i am getting errors for the modules as you may see in the attached screenshot.

I don't expect anyone to solve me those, but can someone write me what will the next steps i should do? Tracking down node_modules one by one? Any suggestions will help me i am sure.

Here is the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { Facebook } from '@capacitor-community/facebook-login';
import { AppData } from './services/app-data/app-data';
import { UserData } from './services/user-data/user-data';
import { TranslateConfigService } from './services/translate/translate.service';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media/ngx';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser/ngx';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
import { Share } from '@capacitor/share';
//import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
import { IOSFilePicker } from '@ionic-native/file-picker/ngx';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { IonMarqueeModule } from "./ion-marquee"
import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';


import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { UserProfileModalPageModule } from './pages/user-profile-modal/user-profile-modal.module';
import { UserProfilePopoverComponent } from './components/user-profile-popover/user-profile-popover.component';


import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization/ngx';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, UserProfilePopoverComponent],
  entryComponents: [UserProfilePopoverComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(
      { animated: false }
    ),

    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    IonMarqueeModule,
    //AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    UserProfileModalPageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Facebook,
    AppData,
    UserData,
    TranslateConfigService,
    SplashScreen,
    Camera,
    StreamingMedia,
    Device,
    MediaCapture,
    Media,
    FileTransfer,
    FCM,
    Meta,
    Globalization,
    TranslateService,
    Share,
    Geolocation,
    NativeGeocoder,
    IOSFilePicker,
    File,
    FileChooser,
    FileTransfer,
    FileTransferObject,
    GooglePlus,
    Push,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://capacitorjs.com/cordova

also https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6

Your old plugin supports only cordova, you need to remove an old plugin and install a new plugin one by one.

```
# Remove a Cordova plugin
npm uninstall cordova-plugin-name
npx cap sync

# Delete Cordova folders and files
rm config.xml
rm -R platforms/ plugins/
```

For installing a new plugin, see e.g.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen

Comment: For your information, Capacitor supports most of the cordova plugins. Only the native platform specific plugins like geo-location,firebase needs migration. But plugins that not related to system specific resources are supported.  Before installing a plugin please read the plugin documentation from top to bottom. There they mention the cordova plugin's compatibility with capacitor.